# Why Genymotion is more light than Android Studio's AVD ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion, android-virtual-device

So I'm new in Android and how my notebook isn't quick I prefered run my app with Genymotion, but I would like to know why the AVD from Android Studio is so heavy and slow.
My PC always have crashed with AVD.

Do you also use Genymotion or AVD or other emulator?

Answer (score 0):

When I started doing Android Programming, I used Genymotion because it is very light and fast. But after sometime, I started using a real a real Android device.

So I'll prefer to use a real device if available. If you don't have a real device, you should choose Genymotion.